# Interchange location of two views

Tags: android

In my activity there are two views. Both are in different parents. I have their coordinates with respect to the screen. How to interchange the location of the two views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to call the parent ViewGroup method `removeView()` for both views then `addView()` to add them back but swapper about.

So if your parent views are called mommy and daddy, one has a child called foo, the other a child called bar:

```
ViewGroup daddy = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.daddy);
ViewGroup mommy = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.mommy);

View foo = findViewById(R.id.foo);
View bar = findViewById(R.id.bar);

//detach children

daddy.removeView(foo);
mommy.removeView(bar);

//re-attach children

daddy.addView(bar);
mommy.addView(foo);
```

Read the reference for [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) for more information about the removeView and addView methods and to see other available methods.

Comment: I do not know the id of the viewgroups. How to get the viewgroup of a view ?

Comment: You could just use the views getParent method on the child views

Comment: Each parent has more than two views, so exact interchange is not happening.

Comment: you can use the other version, `addView(View child, int index)` to specify the position at which to add the child into the parent

Comment: to add to the previous comment if you need to find the original position of a child you can call `indexOfChild(View child)` on its parent.  This is all on the documentation I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int x1 = view1.getX();
int y1 = view1.getY();

view1.setX(view2.getX());
view1.setY(view2.getY());
view2.setX(x1);
view2.setY(y1);
```

You could also consider an animation effect to make this look nice.

Comment: Merlin is correct, I missed the part about them belong to different parents

Comment: also `setX` is available since API 11 only