# How to get x,y coordinates

Tags: android, android-layout

One of the activities in my Android app  has a relative layout with two imageviews, which are set up in an xml layout file. How can I programmatically get x,y location of the imageviews

Will these coordinates be different dependent on screen size and density?

What I want to do is have the user touch image1 which will then be animated to move to the location of image2.

Obviously, since I placed these images in the xml I know their x,y coordinates, but I'm concerned that these coordinates will vary dependent on the screen size and density.

Comment: and what will be the position of image2 ?

Comment: Also when you place the `ImageView` in xml, make sure you are using 30dp instead of 30px. Check here for what that means: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `View.getTop(), View.getBottom(), View.getLeft(), and View.getRight()`. These will return the location of the `top, bottom, left and right` edge of the View relative to the parent.

Comment: As per this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/20991950/2162226, the view needs to have been actually rendered in order for the methods to work correctly: *"You need your view added to a layout and displayed (At least one layout pass and measure pass must have run.)"*.  Thanks for the solt!

Answer (score 1):

How to get x and y

```
int[] t = new int[2];
int[] cordinatesofImageView1 = imageView1.getLocationOnScreen(t);


int[] cordinatesofImageView2 = imageView2.getLocationOnScreen(t);
```

You have to adjust your control w.r.t of screen size and Here is the link that how can you detect that.

[Determine device screen category (small, normal, large, xlarge) using code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015094/determine-device-screen-category-small-normal-large-xlarge-using-code)

OR

You can refer to this answer this may help you.

[Interchange location of two views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458660/interchange-location-of-two-views)

Thanks :)

Comment: There's no getX, getY methods on an imageView. It's getTop, getLeft, getBottom, getRight as Jason describes in his answer below.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience I have edited my code, this time it will surely help you. Thanks :)