# android .getTop() returns 0.0

Tags: java, android, xml

I am developing an android lock screen app. I got the idea from another thread to check the coordinates of where the finger has pressed down against to the coordinates of the imagebutton that I have set up.

I am trying to get the coordinates of the imagebutton using the `.getTop()` and `.getLeft()` but both are returning 0.0 (as they are floats, not int).

why is this? I am new to android development, so sorry if I am missing something obvious.

Also, I read somewhere that the `.getTop()` won't work after the `setContentView(R.layout.layoutname)` but if I put it above `setContentView(...)` then the app crashes.

Is there another way to get the coordinates of the imagebutton, or would it be better/easier to get the coordinates and bounds of the table cell ? How would I do that?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932253/get-positions-of-views-in-a-dialog-relativ-to-their-parent/19933242#19933242) link should help you.

Answer (score 6):

You need your view added to a layout **and displayed** (At least one layout pass and measure pass must have run.). Also, the co-ordinates so obtained are relative to view's immediate parent.

> It is possible to retrieve the location of a view by invoking the
>   methods getLeft() and getTop(). The former returns the left, or X,
>   coordinate of the rectangle representing the view. The latter returns
>   the top, or Y, coordinate of the rectangle representing the view.
>   These methods both return the location of the view **relative to its
>   parent**. For instance, when getLeft() returns 20, that means the view
>   is located 20 pixels to the right of the left edge of its direct
>   parent.

Comment: For ensure the view has displayed invoking the methods inside onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)

Answer (score 2):

```
imagebutton.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
```

try this before imagebutton.getTop()?

Comment: I get this error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to float`

Comment: `measure()` This is called to find out how big a view should be. The parent supplies constraint information in the width and height parameters. you should call measure before you call `getTop()`.clear?

Answer (score 2):

I came across this problem when calling `.getTop()` from within `onCreateView()` or `onViewCreated()`.
In this state, the Views were not yet drawn and hence the actual coordinates are not known yet.

One workaround is to make the values be read in the following UI cycle using a handler:

```java
int buttonTop;
int buttonLeft;

// ...

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final ImageButton imageButton = view.findViewById(R.id.your_imagebutton_id);

    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {
        buttonTop = imageButton.getTop(); 
        buttonLeft = imageButton.getLeft(); 
    });
}
```

Comment: Sent a bounty for amazing answer.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the job ;)

```
// Your view
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

Rect rect = new Rect();
image;getLocalVisibleRect(rect);
Log.d("WIDTH :",String.valueOf(rect.width()));
Log.d("HEIGHT :",String.valueOf(rect.height()));
Log.d("left :",String.valueOf(rect.left));
Log.d("right :",String.valueOf(rect.right));
Log.d("top :",String.valueOf(rect.top));
Log.d("bottom :",String.valueOf(rect.bottom));`
```

Comment: It still results in `0` for all of them. would this work with imagebutton or only imageview?

Comment: It should work with any view. Did you put `setContentView` before ?

Comment: Yes I setup all the variables after the `setContentView` or it crashes